# How to put the specific date using aggregate of mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I elaborated the date using momentJS. And I want to put this directly in aggregate of mongoose.

```
  from = "2020-01-29"

  let utcFrom = '';
  utcFrom = `${moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DD')} 00:00:00`;
  utcFrom = moment(utcFrom)
    .subtract(3, 'hours')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

  console.log(utcFrom) // 2020-01-28T21:00:00

  Users = await user.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          orderTime: {
            $gte: utcFrom,
            $lte: utcTo
          },
        }
    ]);
```

But It doesn't work at all and I have to put as below instead.
However, I think new Date change 'utcFrom' one more time substracting 3 hours.
How can I put without changing date directly?
Thank you so much for reading it.

```
$gte: new Date(utcFrom)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 from = "2020-01-29",
    to = "2020-01-01"
    var start = moment.utc(from).format()
    var end = moment.utc(to).format()
    Users = await user.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              orderTime: {
                $gte: start,
                $lte: end
              },
            }
        ]);
this will work...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   from = "2020-01-29",
    to = "2020-01-01"
    var start = moment.utc(from).format()
    var end = moment.utc(to).format()
    Users = await user.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              orderTime: {
                $gte: start,
                $lte: end
              },
            }
        ]);
```

Comment: I want to put date without using new Date. Because it works depends on server time.